# on_touch_down не дает нажать кнопку Kivy&Python

Tags: python, kivy

Есть Button, которая при нажатие пишет "pause".
Есть Label, который показывает кол-во кликов.

Все нормально работало, но до того момента когда я захотел подключить on_touch_down для фиксирование кликов.После подключения, Button перестала работать.
Как это Исправить?

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
import random

Window.size = (320,640)
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
class Menu(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.score = 0
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.ids.lbl.text = str(self.score)
        self.score += 1
        print(self.score)
class Main(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

.kv

```
Manager:
    Menu:
        name:'menu'
<Menu>:
    Button:
        text: 'fds'
        size_hint: .2,.2
        on_release:
            print('pause')
    Label:
        id: lbl
        text: ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.ids.lbl.text = str(self.score)
        self.score += 1
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)
```